# Visual Studio MVC Site.css changes not taking effect

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I tried changing some attributes of MVC application Site.css but running it doesn't seem to recognize the changes because I don't see any of them in effect. Why is this? I am just new to ASP.NET MVC project development.

Answer (score 2):

Please elaborate on what are the changes you made? Makes sure you are referring the correct version of site.css. Also try Ctrl + F5 to replace your cached version of css.